# Paypal, redirect user back to the same url he came from

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have pay now form on my page and after user finishes his payment i want him to return to the same url he came from, is that possible?

Maybe i need to use those `Advanced variables` for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you could use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` in a PayPal form as return URL like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yourdomain.tld<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to pass the URL he came from to the paypal API return variable.

See the return variable in the paypal docs:
[HTML Variables for Displaying PayPal Checkout Pages](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0709B)

> **return** (Optional)
>
> The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers’ browser
>   after they complete their payments. For example, specify a URL on your
>   site that displays a “Thank you for your payment” page.
>
> Default – PayPal redirects the browser to a PayPal webpage.